# C# Check All from a CheckedListBox without showing the "Check All" entry

Tags: c#, loops, checkbox, checkedlistbox

I have a small program that has several checkedboxlists in VS2010. I wanted to allow a user to select all in one of the lists and came up with this looping structure...

```
private void CheckedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
        {
            Applications.Add(CheckedListBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString());
        }
        else if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Unchecked)
        {
            Applications.Remove(CheckedListBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString());
        } 
    }

private void CheckedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (CheckedListBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < CheckedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                CheckedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(0));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (!CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(CheckedListBox1.SelectedIndex))
            {
                CheckedListBox1.SetItemChecked(0, false);
            }
        }

    }
```

The problem is this also puts the "Select All" checkbox into the output. Is there a way I can tweak the loop to not include the first checkbox (which is the "Select All" Check) or should I be going about this a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty unclear what "into the output" might mean.  Using the SelectedIndexChanged event isn't very appropriate, the ItemCheck event signals checking an item.  Try this instead:

```
    private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Index == 0) {
            for (int item = 1; item < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; item++) {
                checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(item, true);
            }
            e.NewValue = CheckState.Unchecked;  // Prevent "Check All" from getting checked
        }
    }
```

If you want to use SelectedIndexChanged anyway then still keep this event handler to prevent the item from getting checked.

Comment: Sorry, I should have included my itemcheck event. I have edited the example code to show this. The output is stored in a list collection and then emailed out useing a diffrent class.

Comment: This is perfect! I took out my SelectIndexChanged and added this code to my ItemCheckEvent and it works absolutely perfect. Thanks a bunch. I'm very new and have been stuck on this for a while. Thanks again!